# Can Custom Controls Be Combined with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, custom-controls

I'm trying to find out if custom user controls can be combined with Ajax but I can't seem to find an answer, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, without question. In fact the WHOLE long time and popular AjaxToolKit here is near 100% based on this concept:

http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/

Try the above sample site - near every single control example is based around a control, and a ajax enabled one at that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes another way is using the `Page.ClientScript` object.  There you have options to use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8) or [RegisterStartupScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8) methods as in:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "SayHello", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert("Hello");</script>");
```

The first parameter is a type reference; simply passing in the object type you are in is fine enough.  The second parameter is any arbitrary string.